# shell_exec to run a large data processing

Tags: php, shell-exec

I was trying to run a php file on the background using `shell_exec`. But upon, adding that code on a php file it just keeps loading until the process is completed. This is my sample code below:

I have a button that will redirect to sync_to_products.php and inside that code is my shell_exec.

This is my code in sync_to_product.php and this is just keeps loading until it is completed.

```
include_once('../conn.php');

session_start();

$product_sku = isset($_GET['product_sku']) ? $_GET['product_sku'] : "";
$feed = isset($_GET['feed']) ? $_GET['feed'] : "";
$current_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$products_session = isset($_SESSION['products']) ? $_SESSION['products'] : '';

if(empty($product_sku)){
    $selected_products = "";
    if(!empty($products_session)){
        $product_ids = array_keys($products_session);
        $product_ids = implode(",", $product_ids);
        $selected_products = "selected_products:\"".$product_ids."\"";
    }
    shell_exec("cd ".ROOT_DIRECTORY." && php functions.php current_domain:\"".$current_domain."\" $selected_products >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: my-page.php");
}
```

I also tried adding `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &` after the command but still it just keeps loading..

The data is about around 20k products that needs to process.

Comment: I think you forgot some dots around $selected_products variable inside the command for completing the text concatenation.
[shell_exec("cd ".ROOT_DIRECTORY." && php functions.php current_domain:\"".$current_domain."\" .$selected_products .">/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");]

Comment: @AliIsmaeel `$selected_products` is inside double quotes, so there are no missing dots to concatenate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're using `&&`, so both return values have to be evaluated. Use `;` instead.

```
shell_exec("cd ".ROOT_DIRECTORY." ; php functions.php current_domain:\"".$current_domain."\" $selected_products >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

should be working just fine in the background.

Comment: Thank you, it works! So the meaning of `;` is there is 2 executed commands in 1 run of shell_exec?

Comment: Yes, commands separated by `;` will run left to right, no matter what their return values are.